# Make JQxGrid Read Only

Tags: grid, jqxgrid

I have a jqxGrid with 5 columns and dynamic rows. I need to enable/disable or read-only true/false the grid on click of a button. is there a way to apply the property of disable/enable to the entire grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$('#GRID ID).jqxGrid({ editable: false});` to make to disabled and `$('#GRID ID).jqxGrid({ editable: true});` to make it editable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called "editable" which enables/disables the Grid's editing and makes it "read-only"